# Check if User has a certain role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have code in which you can type `-giverole <user> <rolename>` e.g. `-giverole @Soup Board of Executives`.
What I need now is a method that checks to see if the user typing the command has a certain role.

I have code that can give a role to someone:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await client.say("The role '" + str(role) + "' has been given to " + member.mention + " .")
```

It should do `await client.say()` if the user has the right rank. If they don't, then it raises an error message.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your Post sadly does not contain a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`commands.has_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role) check to determine whether or not the person invoking the command has a particular role:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_role("Role Name")
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await client.say(f"The role '{role}' has been given to {member.mention}.")
```

When someone without the role tries to invoke it, a [`commands.CheckFailure` error will be raised](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks).  You can then [handle that error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) if you want the bot to say something:

```
@giverole.error
async def giverole_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "You are lacking a required role")
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: Thanks. My code raises an error. "has_role isn't defined". How would I fix this?

Comment: You need to import it: `from discord.ext.commands import has_role`

Comment: Oh thanks. I thought of that however I put `from discord.ext import has_role`. Thanks a lot. I am a beginner to coding bots with Python using discord API. This really helps :)

Comment: Do you also know how to have multiple arguments for the `has_role`. For example, they could have the Board of Executives role or they can have the Moderation Manager role.

Comment: There is another check called [`has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role) that does that

Comment: Thanks bud. This really helps.

Comment: Can you do `await client.say()` with a multiple line message. The message I want is:

`Welcome to your Moderation Interview.`

Q1)

However line gaps between each part.

Comment: I think so. Try putting a newline literal `\n`  wherever you want a line break: `"Welcome.\nHello"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [discord.Member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles) to do something like

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
  check_role = get(ctx.message.server.roles, name='Board of Executives')
  if check_role not in member.roles:
    await client.say(f"You don't have the role '{str(role)}'")
  else:
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await client.say(f"The role '{str(role)}' has been given to {member.mention}.")
```