# how do I check if a user has a specific role in discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

This should check if the specific person does or doesn't have the mute role

```
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_role("Admin")
    async def unmute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Member', 
    ctx.message.server.roles)
        if user.has_role(role):
            await bot.say("{} is not muted".format(user))
        else:
            await bot.add_roles(user, role)
```

This error is thrown

> Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'has_role'

I don't know how to do it so i would really appreciate every help I can get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if User has a certain role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324466/check-if-user-has-a-certain-role)

Comment: @Tristo From what i understand the linked questions if asking if the user invoking the command has a role, not the user passed into the function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Member does not have a `.has_role()` method, you can however get a list of all their roles using `.roles`.

To see if a user has a given role we can use `role in user.roles`.

```
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_role("Admin")
    async def unmute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Member', ctx.message.guild.roles)
        if role in user.roles:
            await bot.say("{} is not muted".format(user))
        else:
            await bot.add_roles(user, role)
```

Docs for reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member

**Note:** `ctx.message.guild.roles` use to be `ctx.message.server.roles`. Updated due to API change.

Comment: `ctx.guild.roles` would be shorter and also works

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def unmute (ctx,user:discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

  if role in user.roles:
    await user.remove_roles(role)

    await user.add_roles(role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Unmuute Members", description=f"{user.mention} has been unmuted" , color = discord.Color.blue())


    embed.add_field(name='Unmuted by:' , value = f"{ctx.author.mention}")


    await user.remove_roles(role)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  else:
    await ctx.send("Invalid Argumnets or The user is not muted.")
```

So as you can see

`role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")` this variable locates the Muted role in the server

```
if role in user.roles:
    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

and this will remove the **role** from the **user**