# checking if message author has a certain role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making an automatic banning system with a discord bot.
So once a message with a steam id is placed into the channel, it will run through an API and ban them (I've got this working)

what I am looking for is to check if that user has a certain role or not.

For this I am using a `@client.listen("on_message")` because the messages usually look like this "[steam id] hacker" and so discord ext wont work because its always looking for its prefix first.

so I am looking at like this:

```
if author.has_role(role_id_here):
   # do something

else:
   # do nothing
```

hopefully this is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I check if a user has a specific role in discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845875/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-has-a-specific-role-in-discord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can either use the name of the role `'role' in list(role.name for role in message.author.roles)`

But you want search by ID, so use `roleID in list(role.id for role in message.author.roles)`

Comment: My method works, but have a look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845875/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-has-a-specific-role-in-discord?noredirect=1&lq=1` anyway