# How to fix: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, discord.py, indentation

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make a discord bot.

#### Code

The following code provides the ability to change the server name.

```py
    try:
        await role.edit(permissions=discord.Permissions.all())
        print(
            f"{C.GREEN}Successfully granted admin permissions in {C.WHITE}{guild.name}"
        )
    except:
        print(f"{C.RED}Admin permissions NOT GRANTED in {C.WHITE}{guild.name}")
        
        
      await ctx.guild.edit("Name")
      
    for channel in guild.channels:
        try
```

#### Problem

However, I am running into this error:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

I hope that someone is able to guide me in resolving the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

It appears your second `await` statement is not correctly indented, I have attempted to correct it. It also depends on, which part of the code, you wish for the `await` to trigger. I am assuming that, it would be placed, outside the `except` block.

```py
    try:
        await role.edit(permissions=discord.Permissions.all())
        print(
            f"{C.GREEN}Successfully granted admin permissions in {C.WHITE}{guild.name}"
        )

    except:
        print(f"{C.RED}Admin permissions NOT GRANTED in {C.WHITE}{guild.name}")

    await ctx.guild.edit("Name")  # Corrected to match indentation.

    for channel in guild.channels:
        pass
```

Depending on which code editor you are using, there are various extensions for linting Python. You may look up linters such as PyLint and Flake8 to get started.

Example of indentation error:
[image]

Result of Flake8:
[image]

Additionally, there is a simpler way to check if the user has a specific role before running the command. Refer to the following URLs. This would make your code much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Check role documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.has_role 
Implementation example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54329741/6893561